# Ways to dodge exchange rates at partypoker?

Tags: online

I am planning on making a **first** deposit on partypoker to play tournaments. I live in the Netherlands, where the euro is used. Depositing and withdrawing from euro to dollar and back costs me a total of 6%.

I have read old posts and some suggested me to use paypal or skrill, while others suggested I simply change my main currency on partypoker to euro and then when buying into tournaments the euros are converted to dollars with a fair exchange rate. I am not sure if this is correct, though. Has anyone got any experience with this lately? Or anyone who got a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Only Make deposits when exchange rates are favourable, I think its laughable at the moment that most sites use dollar as a base currency.

This would have made sense when the sites were primarily US based, however seeing as most of the market is not currently, I feel it would make more sense to use EUR.

**edit** this is not a plug, as I am just a fan of their service, but revolut, offer wholesale exchange rates - so you could essentially deposit in whatever currency you like https://revolut.com/

Answer (score -1):

Ask this question to partypoker support.

And if you still have problems/questions, place their answer here and then we will find a solution

Comment: I already asked for support. If you are not answering the question, it is better to comment on my post.

Comment: ok, downvote me, and I will win your money on partypoker